# How to use AnimationController in GetX instead of using StatefulWidget and SingleTickerProviderStateMixin

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an `initState()` method and contains `AnimationController` as the below code:

```
_controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 2500,
      ),
    );
```

for example I want to use as the below way:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ControllerViewModel extends GetxController {
  AnimationController _controller;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 2500,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but of course I found an error with `The argument type 'ControllerViewModel' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider'.`

So there's a way to use this `AnimationController` in GetX state management way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a solution just add with`GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin`  to be the full code as the below one:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ControllerViewModel extends GetxController with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 2500,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: update SingleGetTickerProviderMixin to GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin because 'SingleGetTickerProviderMixin' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. use GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement

Answer (score 2):

That is my solution for this case - thanks for @Mahmoud Harooney

```
class CartController extends GetxController with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final ICartService cartService;
  final IOrdersService ordersService;
  late AnimationController _badgeShopCartAnimationController;
  late Animation badgeShopCartAnimation;

  CartController({required this.cartService, required this.ordersService});

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    _badgeShopCartAnimationSetup();
  }

  void addCartItem(Product product) {
    cartService.addCartItem(product);
    _badgeShopCartAnimationPlay();
  }

  void _badgeShopCartAnimationSetup() {
    _badgeShopCartAnimationController =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 225), vsync: this);

    badgeShopCartAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: const Offset(0, 0.0),
      end: const Offset(.2, 0.0),
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _badgeShopCartAnimationController,
        curve: Curves.elasticIn,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _badgeShopCartAnimationPlay() async {
    await _badgeShopCartAnimationController.forward();
    await _badgeShopCartAnimationController.reverse();
  }
}
```